# How to calculate multiple calc() on LESS?

Tags: css, less

How I can get only result from calc ?

```
@winh: `$(window).height()`;
@re: calc(~'@{winh}px - 125px');

.lgrid(@width, @height) {
    height: ~"@{re} * 21.25% * @{height}" !important;
}
```

Result on my file.less

```
height: calc(675px - 125px) * 21.25% * 4 !important;
```

I try another way with

```
height: calc(~"@{re} * 21.25% * @{height}") !important;
```

but I have multiple calc

```
calc(calc(675px - 125px) * 21.25% * 4) !important;
```

But it's not working on my browser (chrome).
How I can calc this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use the css `calc()` function as your final calculator, then you would need your LESS code to be something like this:

```
height: ~"calc(@{re} * calc(21.25% * @{height}))" !important;
```

Producing css like this:

```
height: calc(calc(601px - 125px) * calc(21.25% * 4)) !important;
```

But it probably would be best to do all the calculations in LESS, which is challenging because of [bugginess](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/387) at present, so really it needs to be all in the javascript. Maybe something more like this:

```
@winh: `$(window).height()`;

.lgrid(@width, @height) {
  @calcHeight: `function(){return (@{winh} - 125) * (.2125 * @{height})}()`;
  height: ~"@{calcHeight}px" !important;
}
```

This assumes the final result is intended to be pixels.